# Rails 3 HTTP digest authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-authentication, digest-authentication

Is HTTP digest authentication still supported in Rails 3?

I tried the following code in Rails 2.3.5, it works.

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate
  USERS = { "lifo" => "world" }
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest("Application") do |name|
      USERS[name]
    end
  end
end
```

Now, the same thing in Rails 3.0.0.beta returns an error:

```
can't convert nil into String
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Rails 3? HTTP basic authentication works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem in Rails beta2.

A quick and dirty fix:

add

```
self.config.secret = "result of rake secret"
```

before

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest("Application")
```